# How to make a Popup Control as Modal in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, messagebox, caliburn.micro

First of all I am using Caliburn Micro for handling MVVM in my project.

Instead of using `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show()`, I have implemented my own MessageBox using caliburn Micro.

```
windowManager.ShowPopup(viewModel);
```

But now, I want this Popup to be model, so that the user cannot interact with other UI, unless the MessageBox recieves an feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `WindowManager.ShowPopup`, you can use `WindowManager.ShowDialog`.  This should place your ViewModel into a modal dialog and show it.

Comment: No, I am not able to get my needed design with ShowDialog.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Part of the problem is that popup controls, by design, are not modal...

Answer (score 0):

You did not express what design you cannot get with ShowDialog so kind of have to guess.

As Reed +1 said ShowPopup is not modal.

Would NavigationWindow.ShowDialog give you what you want?  You can host a Page in NavigationWindow.

[NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow_methods.aspx)

Comment: i am not creating navigationBased application.. my app is something like MDI

Comment: Did you like try it?  Just because it says Navigation does not mean it has to be used in that capacity.  From the documentation "Represents a window that supports content navigation."  What about it does not work?  What about ShowDialog does not work?  We can't really help you if all you give us is doesn't work.